# Is it true that a set with dim(span($S$)) = $n$ must contain $n$ linearly independent vectors itself?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $S$ is some arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is such that the dimension of the span of $S$ is equal to $n$.  i.e. span($S$) contains a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Is it true that there exist $n$ linearly independent vectors *within* $S$?  It seems like it must be true intuitively, but I cannot prove it rigorously.

Comment: Hint:  how could it not?

Comment: Consider the largest linearly independent subset of $S$, and its size.

Comment: This is what I tried.  I'm really not sure how to argue this so trivially as you guys make it seem.  If $S$ does not contain a set of LI vectors, but span($S$) does, say they are given by $$x_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} a_{ij} s_{ij} \quad \quad i \in \{1, ..., n\} $$ with $s_{ij} \in S$.  I have no idea how to proceed to show a contradiction from here.

Comment: Let $T\subset S$ be a largest linearly independent subset of $S$ with size $<n$. Then by maximality of $T$ we must have $S\setminus T$ is in  the span of $T$ so Span$(T)$=Span$(S)$ has dimension less than $n$, which is a contradiction. So dim(Span$(T))=n$.

Comment: Ok thanks!  I'm supremely unintelligent and I honestly apologize for this question.  Cheers

Comment: Don't insult yourself or apologize for being confused about something. Even the most brilliant people get stuck from time-to-time because they overlooked something, and their thoughts on it keep following the same path, making the same error unnoticed. I cannot tell you how many times I have thought I found something, then set it aside for a week or two (a useful trick), only to wonder "what the heck was I thinking" when I picked it back up again. (Though I don't count as being among "the most brilliant".)